# jQuery.html() result, not interpreted as HTML by the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

After a successful ajax call, I want to print the result on screen (in a DIV). 
This result is a piece of HTML code.

```
$.ajax({
    url: window.location.pathname + '/feedback-campaigns',
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'text/html',
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        var result = data.campaigns.campaigns[0].text; 
        // result = "&lt;b&gt;TEST - do you see me?&lt;/b&gt;"
        $('.campaign-top-product-detail-page').html(result);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('NOK');
    }
});
```

But, on screen I see this:

```
<b>TEST - do you see me?</b>
```

instead of the text in bold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use following**

```
$.ajax({
           url: window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + '/feedback-campaigns',
           type: 'GET',
           contentType: 'text/html',
           success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    var result = $.parseHTML(data.campaigns.campaigns[0].text); // result = "&lt;b&gt;TEST - do you see me?&lt;/b&gt;"
                    $('.campaign-top-product-detail-page').html(result);  
          },
          error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log('NOK');
          }
});
```

Update: write like this `$.parseHTML(data.campaigns.campaigns[0].text);`

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: parseHTML is not defined

Comment: Make it correct-----   $.parseHTML(data.campaigns.campaigns[0].text)

Comment: It works, thanks! 
However, I had to add something:

    var result2 = $.parseHTML(data.campaigns.campaigns[0].text)[0].data;

Answer (score 3):

It is because the response from server contains HTML entities, not actual HTML tags. To solve this, simply send the HTML such as `<b>TEST - do you see me?</b>`. (If you're using PHP on your server, then don't use `htmlspecialchars` on the output).

Answer (score 0):

Remember that things like `&lt` will be not regarded as a part of HTML code but some character. So if you want to show the text which is bold, you should let it return as below

```
<b>TEST - do you see me?</b>
```

However, if you don't have permission to edit the result, other answers are good.